# How to use Tornado work with Django? Is it a good solution?

Tags: django, tornado, instagram

I've a huge django project and have to use Instagram API and its subscriptions model to work. For the subscriptions, my server has to be very responsive and be ready to work asynchronously to set up a hook so as to receive notifications once the user posts. Or that's what the documentation suggests. Now will it be a good thing to use Tornado there? Just for that small part or can I do it using Django in an effective way? if so, how?

Comment: Write widget using tornado and integrate it into django application using ajax.

Comment: Tornado wouldn't be idea for this; look towards `node.js`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Why do you think there will be a big difference between `Tornado` and `node.js`?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the WSGI container on top of Tornado to host any WSGI application, including Django, however, when you do that the WSGI application is still running as a blocking application and will not magically be running as an asynchronous application. So, when Django is handling a request there is no ability to handle another request at the same time within Django. The solution at that point is not much different to running a single threaded WSGI server and you would need to have multiple Tornado instances to handle concurrent requests.

So all really depends on what you mean by asynchronous. You certainly can't make use of Tornado's direct asynchronous programming API in Django. Thus there isn't really any great benefit from using Tornado with Django via the WSGI interface.

Comment: I wonder why so many people have mentioned this setup? Thanks for the info so I don't waste my time trying to converge the two.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you are talking about this paragraph in [Instagram docs](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)

> You should build your system to accept multiple update objects per payload - though often there will be only one included. Also, you should acknowledge the POST within a 2 second timeout--if you need to do more processing of the received information, you can do so in an asynchronous task.

That's another type of "asynchronous" that Tornado provides.
I think Django + [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) will suite better for this.

Your application will work in this way:

1. You receive JSON-data from Instagram
2. Create a celery-task, e.g. `instagram_process.delay(request.raw_post_data)` or `instagram_process.delay(request.body)` according to your Django version
3. Response to Instagram with 200 status code
4. In `instagram_process` task you do all your procession - parse JSON, store it do database and anything else you need.

If you want to check `X-Hub-Signature` you can either do it between steps 1 and 2, or pass this header to the task and verify the signature at step 4.

Comment: Didn't even think of it in this way. Thank you, sire! Would try to make it work today in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tornado.wsgi to integrate Tornado with other WSGI compliant frameworks. Check out this demo project for details:

https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo

Comment: This solution is slow as Django and WSGI are synchronous, and call such as DB queries will block the whole tornado server. See @graham-dumpleton answer